# What should I include in my Polymer App Shell?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, polymer, progressive-enhancement, progressive-web-apps

I'm starting to dwell into the Progressive Web App environment, I'm using ASP.NET 4.6 and MVC5 for the likes with a Polymer Single Page App. I was wondering what should I include in my App Shell?

So far, I have included the app-location, app-route, app-toolbar, app-drawer-layout, with Polymer vulcanized. The file size is 266 KB and I inject the HTML inline in the first load.

This will only load visually load the navbar. The navbar needs a paper-tab element and my custom login-element. Should I include them in the fist load?

Everything else is lazy-loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I explained in my previous answer.

Let's say you built an element called *lazy-element* that you want to lazy load. It is located at *http://example.com/lazy-element.html*. Here is a way you could load it.

Reference *lazy-element* in your current element.

```
<lazy-element></lazy-element>
```

When your project loads, this element will do nothing because it has not been loaded yet. So, let's create a function to lazy load it. Include this function somewhere in your project (possibly as a private function in the element that we are lazy loading from).

```
_loadElement: function(pathToElement) {
  this.importHref(pathToElement, function() {
    console.log(pathToElement + ' loaded');
  }.bind(this), function() {
    console.warn(pathToElement + ' failed to load');
  }.bind(this));
}
```

Now, call this function loading *lazy-element* whenever you want *lazy-element* to activate in your project. Maybe you want it to activate 5 seconds after your project is ready.

```
ready: function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    this._loadElement('http://example.com/lazy-element.html');
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer!!! I have implemented a somewhat little bit more complex approach. In which the element is lazy loaded according to the selected iron-pages or iron-selector. For achieving that I needed to capture the event that is sent after iron-selected, check if the element has been loaded and use the importHref to achieve it. I'll be writing a tutorial soon on how I achieved that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Just include things you are going to use. If you don't have something you need, then just add it when you realize you need it.

If you want to get really sophisticated, you can lazy load polymer elements using *this.importHref*. However, you have to be careful when lazy loading elements, because they may depend on other polymer elements that end up being lazy loaded creating a long chain of elements that have to be loaded.

Try and keep elements you use frequently in the initial load of the app, and lazy load elements that only get used once or twice at certain locations in the app.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a bunch. I'm working on its implementation right now, do you have any suggestions for lazy loading the elements? I'm using iron-pages with app-route, and what I've been working on, is to capture all the iron-pages' selected element and check it with Polymer to see if it's been loaded or not. It gets a little bit more sophisticated than that, but it's been working. Not that I have other choice. The app takes a brutal 30 seconds to fully load bare bones (only elements without any images or actual content)

Comment: Btw, should I include only the elements needed for the first paint? Or should I include all "common elements" that are being reused in many parts of the app?

Comment: Nice answer @jamrizzi

Comment: I just gave you an example of how to lazy load elements. Please set my first answer as the correct answer to this question.

Comment: By the way, to help with an application that takes forever to load, create a loading spinner that loads before any Polymer stuff loads, and remove it when Polymer is finished loading.